# How to stop jcarousel animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I'm using jcarousel to animate an unordered list but since I need the animation to smoothly transition between items I'm setting the `animation` option to a very large integer, this works fine but I need to start the slide animation when I mouse over some links and stop it on mouse out, this is what I have so far:

```
$(function() {
    function customCallback(carousel) {
        $('.prev').hover(function() {
            // Starts the back animation
            carousel.prev();
        }, function() {
            // How to stop animation?
        });

        $('.next').hover(function() {
            // Starts the forward animation
            carousel.next();
        }, function() {
            // How to stop animation?
        });
    }

    $('.list').jcarousel({
        animation    : 14000,
        wrap         : 'circular',
        easing       : 'linear',
        buttons      : false,
        initCallback : customCallback
    }); 
});​
```

But I don't know how to stop the animation on mouse out, here's a demo to illustrate this better: http://jsfiddle.net/hfuwM/1/

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance

EDIT: I found that using `carousel.list.stop()` on the mouseout callback stops the animation but then it doesn't restart when hovering the links again.

Comment: duplicate ? of this [SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4822102/474535) otherwise try `pause()`

Comment: `pause()` isn't a function and I can't use `stopAuto()` since I'm not triggering the auto event but the scroll one. Using `carousel.list.stop(true, true)` kind of works, it stops the carousel on mouseout but resets it to the initial position :(

Comment: I checked the code and indeed it does not have a stop or pause option. It may be that it requires extension of the plugin to be able to stop/pause the carousel.